# Distinct datasource of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a first table

Table1

```
Idtask. Date.     Geo
1.       2020-01  france
2.       2020-03  inde
```

And I have a second table2
Table2

```
Idtask. Date.     Geo
1.       2020-01  france
2.       2020-03  inde
```

When I do union all between the two table

```
Select *
From table1
Union all
Select *
From table 2
```

I will get results

```
Idtask. Date.     Geo
1.       2020-01  france
2.       2020-03  inde
1.       2020-01  france
2.       2020-03  inde
```

How can I know that Idtask is coming from Table1 or table2? If you've any idea? I add a column 'table 1' as datasource, but I need to make difference based on Idtask to calculate count distinct of Idtask.

Comment: Please include the exact output you really want here, along with an explanation.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know in how many tables is each idtask ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a computed column to your union query which keeps track of the table origin:

```sql
SELECT Idtask, Date, Geo, 1 AS source FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Idtask, Date, Geo, 2 FROM table2;
```

If you needed to, for example, sort your union query by table source, you could subquery the above as follows:

```sql
SELECT IdTask, Date, Geo
FROM
(
    SELECT Idtask, Date, Geo, 1 AS source FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Idtask, Date, Geo, 2 FROM table2
) t
ORDER BY source;
```

Comment: I need to do count distinct on Idtask. This is why I need to distinct the Idtask.

Comment: You can do a count(distinct idtask) to achieve this

Comment: @Sql . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question -- such as calculating a count -- then ask a *new* question.